Bathroom Window Height on Tub side
We want our bathroom window (glazed/obscure) 36 inch wide and 24 inch high to be at shoulder level (about 5.25 feet above ground) and our contractor thinks that's too low.
We already have a similar bathroom and we have not had any complaints from family or guests staying.
What is the code for this if there is one?
What other things should we consider in making this decision?
The contractor thinks the bottom of the window need to be way above average height at 6.5 feet, but that's too high and in my opinion not very accessible. What is the best practice or code?


This isn't intended to be an egress window or something, is it?  If not, RMDman's answer is appropriate.

I fixed your second picture reference, but it appears to be a duplicate of the first picture, though the code is different. It looks like you imported the same picture twice.

Yes, this is not an egress window. Yes by mistake I thought the first upload was not rendering so I uploaded it twice - thanks for fixing.

I had a window like this in a previous house - in winter it was AWESOME to be in a hot-hot shower and yet be breathing cool air.    I miss that.

63 inches (5.25') is well above minimum sill height. There are many bath windows with that approximate sill height in my area.
Unless your contractor can give you proof of a violation of local code he should make the window the height you desire. After all, this is your home.

I have never heard of a code on window height and have seen/replaced quite a few at the height you want. I will mention that what you desire is a lot of work just to lower it approximately one foot. At that lower height, a lot of water will accumulate on the sill and will puddle if not correctly sloped.

thanks for the answer. To give you some more context - we gut out the whole bathroom it was a project that was over due, we changed the orientation of the bathroom, now it's empty, only floor is there and exterior siding. There was a window on that wall (outside wall) but since we wanted to put the tub on that side we wanted to raise the window for privacy reasons. Then the debate opened how high it should be. May be my contractor is not wanting to have to cut the quartz panel to place the window there.

@Rose  If the wall is gutted then definitely go for it.

@Rose   What is right outside that window might be important.  Can see the reason for a higher window if there is a sidewalk right outside or people just walking can just look.

@crip659 - this bathroom is on the second floor. There is the ground floor unit below it.
The widow is on the side of the house and our neighbor has a couple windows facing our home. But luckily our windows are slightly higher than our neighbor's windows.
